# Hiding Bootstrap Tooltips on Mobile using Media Queries

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap's Tooltips over buttons on my site but when viewed on a mobile device, these tooltips are triggered on the first click, meaning I have to double click on the button. I want to prevent these being shown on mobile devices and have tried using media queries to do so. My code has been:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
{
 .tooltip
 {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

This stops the tooltip from displaying, but I still have to click twice to get the button to function. Is there any way I can prevent these tooltips from firing using media queries?

Comment: Can't you touch the JS at all ? One way would be to use 2 buttons : one hidden on small resolutions, and the other without tooltip for small screens. Is that conceivable ?

Comment: I agree Sherbrow. @natlines add visible-desktop to your <a> class where you have tooltip enabled. But fix your button click first. check your trigger setting for the tooltip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483474/twitter-bootstrap-popover-tooltip-bug-with-mobile seems to be almost the same question.

Answer (score 32):

I have achieved it differently; Mobile and other devices are `touch` enabled, so I checked if it's touch device or not.

```
function isTouchDevice(){
    return true == ("ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch);
}
```

Now, check if it's not a `touch device` to trigger the tool-tip:

```
if(isTouchDevice()===false) {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
}
```

Comment: This works. If the tooltip is targeted for the a use this instead:
function isTouchDevice(){
      return true == ("ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch);
      }
      if(isTouchDevice()===false) {
      jQuery(function(e){e("a").tooltip({html:true,container:"body"})});
      }

Answer (score 18):

Just use the !important flag since the tooltip position is styled inline.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .tooltip {
        display: none !important;
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. Why does bootstrap not have this built in by default? Seems like this type of tooltip wouldn't be used widely on mobile.

Comment: @erier this is not built in because on mobile you don't have mouse hover.

Comment: This is the right answer if you need to hide them for certain viewports. Though I don't really understand why you'd NEED to hide them on mobile platforms missing hover events

Answer (score 13):

To enable tooltips, you must be adding something like `$('#example').tooltip(options)` somewhere in your code.

Now, to disable this for mobile devices, you can use JavaScript's [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia) to specify a media query in JavaScript and thus not enable tooltips for smaller devices.

```
if (!window.matchMedia || (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches)) {

    // enable tooltips
    $('#example').tooltip();
}
```

MatchMedia is supported in mobile Safari 5 and up (among other browsers).

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed it, thanks.Just one small change, is that I enabled for non-mobile/non-tablet, meaning I used `if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 991px)").matches)` instead.

Comment: Replace the `max-width` property with `min-width: 768px`, for enabling tooltip on all devices except smartphone (following the Bootstrap 3 standard)

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem, and i found the solution in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/Mc2C41QXdnI

matchMedia lacks support for IE (not an issue on mobile), but also Android 2.2/2.3;  http://caniuse.com/matchmedia

It is also possible to just use window.innerWidth; and check that against the same values, something like:

```
var isMobile;
var isTablet;
var isDesktop;

function detectScreen(){
    innerW = window.innerWidth;
        isDesktop = false;
        isTablet = false;
        isMobile = false;
        if(innerW >= 768 && innerW <= 979){
            isTablet = true;
        }else if(innerW > 979){
            isDesktop = true;
        }else{
            isMobile = true;
        }
        return innerW;
}

$(document).ready(function($) {
    detectScreen();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        detectScreen();
    });
}
```

]

And then you can do the same thing;

```
    if (! isMobile ) {
      initTooltip();
    }
```

Comment: with more than a few tooltips on a page, this may lead to memory leaks because you are reinitializing objects over and over that may not need to be. Be careful of that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add native Bootstrap class **hidden-xs** and tooltips won't show up on mobile screens.

Example:

```html
<span title="Your Tooltip Text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign hidden-xs"></span>
```

Comment: But the element doesn't show up either, just want to turn off tool tips, not hide the element that causes them.

Comment: @RickeyWard you can put another tag for that matter, using the inverse logic, like `<span class="hidden-md hidden-lg"><!-- whatever works better in mobile --></span>`
Also you could add `hidden-sm` to @pdolinaj's answer.
**Edit:** let's forget the question is about Media queries hehe

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, you can use [css hover media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) query to target touch devices that don't have the ability to hover.

```css
@media (hover: none) {
  /* Hover is not supported */
 .tooltip
 {
  display: none;
 }
}
```