# How to hide bootstrap directive tooltip in vuejs for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am working on Vuejs + Laravel.

There is one tooltip directive which uses bootstrap's functionality.

Here it is:

```
window.Vue.directive("tooltip", function(el, binding) {
  // console.log(el, binding);

  window.$(el).tooltip({
    title: binding.value,
    placement: binding.arg ? binding.arg : "right",
    trigger: "hover",
    html: true
  });
});
```

and its usage is like this:

```
<div
            v-tooltip="messages.type_button"
            class="form-group row border-bottom p-2"
          >
```

where

```
message:{
type_button:'Hello World, this is tooltip'
}
```

So this tooltip is working great in desktops but it is causing display issue in mobile device hence we need to hide this tooltip altogether in mobile devices.

Since I have not found any package it uses, so guessing it is a custom directive developed.

We tried hiding using media queries but no help. Can anyone have idea, what should I do ?

Comment: Add a class tooltip (or something else), and hide it with media queries. Show what you tried with media querties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the solution Thanks to [Umezo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903001/hiding-bootstrap-tooltips-on-mobile-using-media-queries/14211162#comment119671014_14211162)

here it is:

```
window.Vue.directive("tooltip", function(el, binding) {
  // console.log(el, binding);

    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 300px)").matches) {

        window.$(el).tooltip({
            title: binding.value,
            placement: binding.arg ? binding.arg : "right",
            trigger: "hover",
            html: true
        });
    }
});
```