# bootstrap popover wont close in mobile

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have simplified my html to the code I post here.
First I have an empty p-tag. Then a table-tag containing a popover-anchor. And then another empty p-tag.
When I am on Desktop, after I click the anchor and the popup displays, wherever I click on the page, the popover will be closed.
However, when I am on mobile (Safari iOS), the popover will only close if I click/tap at the end of the page. Which means, the area after the last empty p-tag. 
I have researched a lot. Im not sure, but maybe could be about listening for "tap" instead of "click"? What I really dont understand is why click outside tags inside body makes the popover to disappear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/jquery/dist/jquery.js">     </script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]')
.on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
})
.popover();
})
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<p style="background-color:green">&nbsp;</p>
<table border=1 cellspacing=2  cellpadding=2 >
    <tr>
       <td><b>Lowest</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
            <a 
                data-html="true"  data-trigger="focus" tabindex="0" role="button" href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" 
                data-content="<div>This is HTML</div>">
                    one
            </a>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<p style="background-color:yellow">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on Iphone onclick on the body element doesnt work.
Try to code a simple html-page where you have this code:
    $(function () {
        $('body').on('click  touchstart', function (e) {
            alert("clicked");
        });
    });
Well, on Iphone there will not be any alert.
So focusing on that, I discovered that there are a few workaround to this.
One workaround is to have a css-directive on the element you want to be clickable (in my case all the body-tag, so in that cse you may want to put some wrapper envolping all the body-content). The directive is simply:
cursor:pointer;

As you probably dont want all the elements to show the pointer, you probably will need to detect if the client was iOS.

Comment: Actually, you can put cursor:pointer inside the body. Tested and it works. The popover disappear when touching somewhere on the page.